# How to setting values in mysql trigger

Tags: mysql

This is mysql query and I want to set avg into variable, and mb.HELP is getting null sometimes and i want to close this ticks. if its null divide 3, when its not, divide 4. Also set value to other column by this value, but query getting syntax error its like ;

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'IF mb.Dynamic_Help  IS NULL THEN
>           SET @newavg := (mb.Dynamic_Delivery_Sp' at line 6

query;

```
CREATE TRIGGER computeColor
AFTER INSERT ON merchant_rates
FOR EACH ROW

   UPDATE merchant_branches as mb
    IF mb.Dynamic_Help  IS NULL THEN
        SET @newavg := (mb.Dynamic_Delivery_Speed + mb.Dynamic_Flavor + mb.Dynamic_Service)/3
     ELSE 
        SET @newavg := (mb.Dynamic_Delivery_Speed + mb.Dynamic_Flavor + mb.Dynamic_Service+mb.Dynamic_Help)/4
    END IF;


CASE
    WHEN @newavg >= 9   THEN  mb.Dynamic_Rank_Color = "#FFD300"
   WHEN @newavg >= 8,5  AND @newavg < 9     THEN  mb.Dynamic_Rank_Color = "#FFD300"
   WHEN @newavg >= 8    AND @newavg < 8,5   THEN  mb.Dynamic_Rank_Color = "#FFD320"
   WHEN @newavg >= 7,5  AND @newavg < 8     THEN  mb.Dynamic_Rank_Color = "#FAD300"
   WHEN @newavg >= 7    AND @newavg < 7,5   THEN  mb.Dynamic_Rank_Color = "#CCD300"
   WHEN @newavg >= 6,5  AND @newavg < 7     THEN  mb.Dynamic_Rank_Color = "#FED300"
END
    WHERE mb.id = NEW.Branch_ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manipulate your update clause to -

```
UPDATE merchant_branches as mb
    SET mb.Dynamic_Rank_Color = CASE 
                                WHEN mb.Dynamic_Help IS NOT NULL
                                THEN
                                    CASE 
                                    WHEN (mb.Dynamic_Delivery_Speed + mb.Dynamic_Flavor + mb.Dynamic_Service+mb.Dynamic_Help)/4 >= 9 THEN "#FFD300"
                                    WHEN (mb.Dynamic_Delivery_Speed + mb.Dynamic_Flavor + mb.Dynamic_Service+mb.Dynamic_Help)/4 BETWEEN 9 AND 8.5 THEN "#FFD300"
                                    WHEN (mb.Dynamic_Delivery_Speed + mb.Dynamic_Flavor + mb.Dynamic_Service+mb.Dynamic_Help)/4 BETWEEN 8.5 AND 8 THEN "#FFD300"
                                    WHEN (mb.Dynamic_Delivery_Speed + mb.Dynamic_Flavor + mb.Dynamic_Service+mb.Dynamic_Help)/4 BETWEEN 8 AND 7.5 THEN "#FAD320"
                                    WHEN (mb.Dynamic_Delivery_Speed + mb.Dynamic_Flavor + mb.Dynamic_Service+mb.Dynamic_Help)/4 BETWEEN 7.5 AND 7 THEN "#CCD300"
                                    WHEN (mb.Dynamic_Delivery_Speed + mb.Dynamic_Flavor + mb.Dynamic_Service+mb.Dynamic_Help)/4 BETWEEN 7 AND 6.5 THEN "#FED300"
                                    END
                                WHEN mb.Dynamic_Help IS NULL
                                THEN
                                    CASE 
                                    WHEN (mb.Dynamic_Delivery_Speed + mb.Dynamic_Flavor + mb.Dynamic_Service)/3 >= 9 THEN "#FFD300"
                                    WHEN (mb.Dynamic_Delivery_Speed + mb.Dynamic_Flavor + mb.Dynamic_Service)/3 BETWEEN 9 AND 8.5 THEN "#FFD300"
                                    WHEN (mb.Dynamic_Delivery_Speed + mb.Dynamic_Flavor + mb.Dynamic_Service)/3 BETWEEN 8.5 AND 8 THEN "#FFD320"
                                    WHEN (mb.Dynamic_Delivery_Speed + mb.Dynamic_Flavor + mb.Dynamic_Service)/3 BETWEEN 8 AND 7.5 THEN "#FAD300"
                                    WHEN (mb.Dynamic_Delivery_Speed + mb.Dynamic_Flavor + mb.Dynamic_Service)/3 BETWEEN 7.5 AND 7 THEN "#CCD300"
                                    WHEN (mb.Dynamic_Delivery_Speed + mb.Dynamic_Flavor + mb.Dynamic_Service)/3 BETWEEN 7 AND 6.5 THEN "#FED300"
                                    END
                                END
    WHERE mb.id = NEW.Branch_ID
```

Comment: Sometimes mb.Dynamic_Help is getting null. What am i gonna do in this condition

Comment: You don't need to take care of that. SQL will count that as null on behalf of you.

Comment: in this case i have to divide this 3, not 4

Comment: Ohhhhh. I did not see that.

Comment: also this is getting syntax error to. but thx for try to help

Comment: @SabriKorkmaz Try now.